# Need very basic advice on contact form

Tags: forms

I'm trying to help my daughter create a contact form for her company's website.
I worked for many years on websites (html, xml, css, flash, photoshop, a little AI, and a little Javascript); no experience with anything server-side.

What I need is a suggestion on the best method to implement a very simple contact form (name, email, message, and submit button).
I need to be able to test it locally.
My daughter will need to make it work on their server, and I don't know if it's a private server or if the site is hosted.

From what I've seen, these contact forms seem to be some combination of html, php, javascript, Ajax, Bootstrap, and jquery.
Is all of that necessary?
I tried one of these program cocktails early this morning, but couldn't test it.  Then I read that it wouldn't work locally. 
I also read that I shouldn't use php mail because of security concerns.
Is that true?

Is there a method that can be tested locally, wouldn't require too much server tweaking, and doesn't pose security problems? 
Thanks so much,
Debbie

Comment: _"some combination of html, php, javascript, Ajax, Bootstrap, and jquery. Is all of that necessary?"_ - the first two are essential (or any other serverside language instead of PHP), the rest is optional sugar on top. You will need some basic knowledge of how forms work (in terms of HTML, and processing the data in serverside language of choice), read up on necessary data validation (specifically in regard to contact forms, so that you don't create every spammer's wet dream) [...]

Comment: [...] And if PHP ends up being the server-side language of choice - then do yourself the favor and don't even try to send email using PHP's `mail` function, but use a library like Swift Mailer or PHPMailer right away. (Please research yourself why you wanna do that, if you need convincing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install MailDev to test in local. You can find some tutorials on the Internet to do contact forms in PHP.
See more here :
http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/